# How to extract sentences from paragraph using grep

Tags: regex, grep

Let's say I have a multiple paragraphs of text , starting and ending with the words START and END.

Example :

```
START i am just and example of a multiline paragraph having some unique informations in each para. I end with a capital END.

START i am just and example of a multiline paragraph having some unique informations in each para. You see in this paragraph I have one extra line.I end with a capital END.
```

How do I extract the content from the words START and END for each of the paragraphs using grep and store in an array.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Your single line sample input text says it's an example of a multi-line paragraph. Please clarify if each paragraph is on a single line or contains newlines and update your sample input/output to match if necessary. Also - can the words START and/or END appear mid-paragraph?

Comment: @Ed Morton If you are simply not capable to answering a question please don't leave unnecessary comments. Look at the solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May you get some idea from this:

Pattern :    (?<=START)(.*)(?=END)

```
**Match 1**
1.  i am just and example of a multiline paragraph having some unique informations in each para. I end with a capital
**Match 2**
1.  i am just and example of a multiline paragraph having some unique informations in each para. You see in this paragraph I have one extra line.I end with a capital
```

https://rubular.com/r/BwL7Wq6vaZdWaC

Comment: Thanks Abimanyu, that helped . It's very close to the solution I have been looking for :)